# Triangle, Circle Problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, analytic-geometry

What is the area $\triangle DEF$ ?

[image]

I solved it using analityc geometry. I want to see if there is way to solve it using plane geometry.
I did it:
$x^2+y^2=400$

$(x+10)^2+y^2=100$

I found the radius fo the red's circle
$\left(x-\frac{20}{3}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{80}{9}\right)^2=\left(\frac{80}{9}\right)^2$

So the tangent line ax+y+c=0 common to both circle is given by the below system :

$|c-10a| = 10\sqrt{a^2+1}$

$\frac{20}{3}a+\frac{80}{9}+c| = \frac{80}{9}\sqrt{a^2+1}$

And so on ...

Thank you for your atention.

Answer (score 1):

may be a mixture method will be quick way.

you already have red one center $O_2 (\dfrac{20}{3},\dfrac{80}{9}),r_2=\dfrac{80}{9}$, connect $O_1O_2$, let it's middle point is $P$,$EF$middle is $Q$,then $DPQ$ will be co-line,

(edit 2)

first check $PQ=\dfrac{O_1O_2}{2}$, put $PG\perp SO_1, G $ fall on $SO_1$  think $\triangle MPQ$ and $\triangle SPO_1$, they are similar.

you can know every thing of $\triangle SPO_1$,you know $MQ=SQ=FQ=\sqrt{r_1r_2}$

now you can write down $DP$  since you know the angle of $MQ\perp O_1O_2$ and you can find out $D$ quickly. now find $|DP|$, it is easy.